# Creating a socket in python

Tags: python, python-import

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#wait to accept a connection - blocking call
conn, addr = s.accept()

#display client information
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
```

While running this file I get

```
  File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/root/socket.py", line 7, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

I want to create a socket to accept connections and read/send data...
Im experiencing this kind of error while doing it.
I am new to python i dont know anything i just got the code from a website.
thankyou

Comment: [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called your file `socket.py` rename it to somethng like `my_socket.py` and delete the `socket.pyc` file in the same directory.

You are trying to import from your `socket.py` file not the actual socket module, python checks the local directory first.

Comment: Quick explanation: When using the `import` statement, Python will **first** look in the current directory for a file that is named like that. So your file is imported instead of the library `socket`

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that the `socket` object does not have an `error` field or attribute

I think it is a naming issue you have since you names your file as the name of socket module. Change the name, might fix the problem.